# Continuity of a function with 2 variables x,y given by $f(x,y)= (1+xy^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

i ran into this question:

check if this function is continuous:

$f(x,y)= (1+xy^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}$ when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$

$f(x,y)= 1$ when $(x,y) = (0,0)$

thanks in advance,

yaron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case $\mathbb{R}^2$ you can consider $x$ and $y$ in polar coordinates: $x=r\cos(\phi), y=r\sin(\phi)$. Then:

$$f(r,\phi)=(1+r^3\cos(\phi)\sin^2(\phi))^{\frac{1}{r^2(sin^2(\phi)+\cos^2(\phi))}}=(1+r^3\cos(\phi)\sin^2(\phi))^{\frac{1}{r^3\cos(\phi)\sin^2(\phi)}\frac{r^3\cos(\phi)\sin^2(\phi)}{r^2}} =(1+r^3\cos(\phi)\sin^2(\phi))^{\frac{1}{r^3\cos(\phi)\sin^2(\phi)}r\cos(\phi)\sin^2(\phi)}\rightarrow e^{0}=1$$ when $r\rightarrow0$, so function is continuous in (0,0).

**EDIT:** Thomas Andrew remarked in comments that we should consider case $\sin(\phi)=0$ separately. Then $f(r,n\pi)=1^{\frac{1}{r^2}}=1$, so the function is still continuous.

Comment: What happens when $\cos \phi = 0$ or $\sin\phi = 0$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Does really using the polar coordinates in such these limits, make us sure of having  the limit?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for remark, just edited.

Comment: @BabakS. Personally, I can't recall if being continuous from every linear direction means being continuous. Not sure why you asked me and not the answerer, however.